# Azure billing - separate invoices

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

Is there a way in Azure to get 2 (or more) separate invoices for consumption of resources created under the same subscription basing on resource group membership? 
Example:

- Resource Group A - with a Sql database - 1 invoice
- Resource Group B - with an App service - 2nd invoice with different
  details

If not, what's the easiest way to achieve separate invoices but keeping same login credentials to the portal? (separate subscription for the same user?)

Answer (score 2):

Invoices NO, but information is already available in the [`Azure portal`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/11261679-provide-cost-information-on-resource-groups). [`Cost analysis`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/quick-acm-cost-analysis) can be found under a subscription and then you can group by resource group name,

[image]

Comment: That I know, but I specifically asked how can I get separate invoices

Comment: As i said answer is NO

Comment: In that case I asked for the easiest alternative solution, I'm pretty sure it's achievable e.g. with separate subscription

Comment: unless you move those resources to the new subscription it is not possible

Comment: Just to confirm, this is correct. The only way to get separate invoices is to move resources to a separate subscription.